# Does this condition lead to a matrix being positive definite?

Tags: probability, matrices

Let $Y$ be a real valued scaler random variable and let $X$ be real valued random vector. Suppose that $E(Y^2 XX')$ is positive definite. Does this imply that $E(XX')$ is positive definite?

I think the intuitive answer would be yes. Consider, for example, the special case where $X$ is a scaler random variable. Then $XX' = X^2$. So $E(XX')$ is not positive definite iff. $E(X^2) = 0$. This in turn means that $X=0$ with probability $1$, so $E(Y^2 XX') = E(Y^2X^2) = 0$. That is, $E(XX') = E(X^2)$ must be positive definite if $E(Y^2 XX') = E(Y^2X^2)$ is positive definite.

But how to argue, when $X$ is a vector?

Best,

Esben

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are not assumed to be independent, then for any $X$, we take $Y = 0$ if $XX'$ is not positive definite, then $E(Y^2XX')$ is positive definite while $E(XX')$ may be not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_n = E\left(\mathbf{1}_{\frac1n<Y<n}\ Y^2XX'\right)$, where $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the indicator function. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} A_n=E(Y^2XX')\succ0$. Hence $A_n\succ0$ for some $n$ and
$$
E(XX')
\succeq E\left(\mathbf{1}_{\frac1n<Y<n}\ XX'\right)
\succeq E\left(\mathbf{1}_{\frac1n<Y<n}\ \frac{1}{n^2}{Y^2}XX'\right)
=\frac1{n^2}A_n \succ0.
$$